# Checking if input contains digits only in C

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I need to check if inserted input (an array which size is determined by user, meaning during run time) contains digits only or not (C99).
While I have an idea of how to do so, it seems to me to be clumsy which led to me ask here if there's any better solution. My "idea" is to receive the input as an array of strings, and then run with a loop over each member to check if it contains non-digit characters. Is there any way better to do so?

Comment: If the input is actually allowed to contain non-digit characters, then read a string and loop and check using the [character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). Otherwise you could use e.g. [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read only decimal numbers (which by definition contain only digits).

Comment: Nope, there is no better way, you have to loop through all the characters in the string. You can use `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`  to determine whether a character is a digit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: if the strings of digits can be really long (say 20 or more), then `scanf()` isn't a good way to read them.  The code will need to take care of newlines, too, presumably.

Comment: Do you want *digits* as defined by Unicode, or specifically the characters `0123456789` ?  For the latter, `strspn` is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you read into an array of lines several lines of text, i.e. you have:

```
char **lines;
int count_lines, i;

count_lines = get_line_count_somehow();
lines = malloc(count_lines*sizeof(*lines));
for (i = 0; i < count_lines; i++)
    lines[i] = get_actual_line_somehow();
```

Now you want to loop through each string. I assume here that `lines[i]` for every value of `i` is `'\0'`-terminated.

```
int contains_digits_only = 1;

for (i = 0; i < count_lines; i++)
{
    char *ptr = lines[i];
    while (*ptr)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*ptr));
        {
             contains_digits_only = 0;
             goto out;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
}
out:
do_something_with(contains_digits_only);
```

Comment: Note that it is possible to incrementally allocate the space in `lines` so that you don't have to read the file twice.  Not all inputs can be rewound (so they can't all be read twice; think pipes, sockets, terminals), and reading a gigabyte or bigger file twice is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Yes, I here assumed that you know the line count in advance. If that is not known in advance, then you want to incrementally allocate space by multiplying size by 2 when growing, not by adding space for one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input using `getchar()`(stdio.h) for optimal performance and then while you are reading the input you can check if the current char is a digit using `isdigit()` which is located inside ctype.h